# Pygame, importing modules

Tags: python, class, import, pygame

I'm making some kind of game, but I only managed to complete the start screen. Now I am trying to make the intro of the first level (so a screen with some explanation and a button to continue). This piece of the program is written in another file so I don't get a file of 1000's of lines.

But now I have a problem. I start my level by using:

```
import level1 # here is my code of the level
level1.level(screen) # "level" is the class and screen is used so pygame 
                     # uses the same screen and doesn't start a new one
```

This is the level1.py:

```
class level():
    def __init__(self,originalscreen):
        screen = originalscreen
        self.levelintro()

    def levelintro(self):
        # Setting some variables
        levelintro = True

        # Background 
        background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size()) # Change this
        background = background.convert()
        background.fill((255,0,0))

        # "Got it" button
        gotitbutton = pygbutton.PygButton((350, 450, 300, 40))

        while levelintro:
            screen.fill(0)  
            # Blitting
            screen.blit(background, (0,0))
            gotitbutton.draw(screen)

            # Refreshing screen
            pygame.display.flip()
```

So now my problem: in my original .py, I imported pygame. But now I tried to import pygame in the level1.py but it doesn't work. How can I import it?

Thx for your help!
Lukas

ps: sorry for my bad english, I am dutch...

Edit:
if I put the "import pygame" in front of my class:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\Project.py", line 17, in <module>
    class startscreen():
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\Project.py", line 51, in startscreen
    level1.level(screen)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\level1.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.levelintro()
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\level1.py", line 15, in levelintro
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size()) # Change this
NameError: global name 'screen' is not defined
```

I don't understand this, because I called the method "level" with level1.level(screen) so it passes the screen and then it sets screen = originalscreen (witch equals the screen from my original file)

If I put "import pygame" inside my class, I get:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\level1.py", line 3
    class level():
SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\Project.py", line 17, in <module>
    class startscreen():
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\Project.py", line 51, in startscreen
    level1.level(screen)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\level1.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.levelintro()
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Google Drive\Project\0.1\level1.py", line 16, in levelintro
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size()) # Change this
NameError: global name 'pygame' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: You say that in your `level1.py` file importing Pygame doesn't work. What do you mean by that? Are you getting an exception when you try it? If so, please add the full traceback to your question.

Comment: i edited my original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it right the first time -- put `import pygame` at the top of the file, not inside the class.

The reason you got the `NameError` telling you that the *global* name `screen` wasn't defined is that it wasn't: when you set `screen = originalscreen` in your `__init__` method, you created a new *local* variable, which disappeared as soon as that method ended. Instead, use `self.screen`; that is, store it as an instance variable on the `level` object.

Replace every instance of `screen` with `self.screen` in both the `__init__` and `levelintro` methods of your `level` class, and your `NameError` problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you so much! It clearly was a stupid error, I still have to learn a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! If you're all set, you can accept this answer by clicking the green check mark to the left.

Comment: Done :) Now i can restart programming!